# Please explain how this link works

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink, download

I ran across some legacy code which creates a link to a file on the web server and offers the user a link to download the file.

I want to fully understand it how it works.

**machine name**:

```
MYSERVER
```

**url**:

```
http://localhost/site/
```

**full url path to the directory** containing the file to download:

```
http://localhost/site/home/target/
```

**target file name**:

```
downloadable.txt
```

The code does the following to create a link to 'downloadable.txt'

```
server.machinename.tostring & "\..\target\downloadable.txt"
```

Which results in:

```
"MYSERVER\..\target\downloadable.txt"
```

That link appears on the page as:

```
<a href="MYSERVER\..\target.downloadable.txt">download this file</a>
```

In **IE 7**, mousing over the link shows the full URL `"http://localhost/site/home/target/downloadable.txt"` in the status bar.  And it works fine for downloading the file in IE 7 (left or right-click).

**Firefox** shows `"http://localhost/site/home/MYS....\target\downloadable.txt"` in the status bar and downloading the file isn't as straight forward.  FF actually tries to change the file name to include the server name and target directory in the file name.

I've tried other methods like `WebClient.DownloadFile()` and had no success.  This works, but I'm unfamiliar with the **"\..\"** and curious about how it works.

**Edit**:

I understand that ".." typically means go up one directory.  My
question was really more in the line of "how does that get interpreted
in the browser to sort out the path?"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the aspx file that is used to create the link is housed in a subdirectory.  So it is traversing back to the home directory and then down to the target directory.. The ..\ means my current directory then move it its parent directory (up one level which should put you into the home directory) and then down into the target directory.
In .Net 2.0 you should use the ResolveURL method.  This would eliviate some of the confusion for you as it would read ResolveURL("~\target\downloadfile.txt").  The tilde puts it at the home directory for the website that is defined in IIS.

Comment: The code is executing from the "home" directory. It creates the sub dir "target" and put the file there.  ResolveURL only works when including the home dir ("~\home\target\downloadable.txt").

Comment: Hmm, would have to see the entire code to determine how you are ending up in a subdirectory in order to do a parent level file structure command... However, if you use resolveURL, you can get to the file anywhere within your application.  I apologize but I did not realize the structure was site\home.  This being the case, then yes you need the ~\home\target..... structure.

Answer (score 3):

```
..\
```

means go back a directory (to the parent of the current directory)

you can put as many of these together as you like...

```
..\..\..\projects
```

would mean go back three directories then into a folder in there called projects

Answer (score 2):

`..` just means 'up one level'.

By the way, on windows the directory separator is `\`, but in URLs it should be `/`. Also, try to avoid creating links with `..` in them, just link straight to the file using it's absolute path.

Comment: Exactly my initial thought.  I wanted to avoid the ".." in the link - but linking to the absolute path isn't working.

Comment: So what is the URL of the page that you are having this issue on? Is it `http://localhost/site/`? If so, the url you want to link to for the file should just be `home/target/downloadable.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The double dot (..) specifies a file  located in the parent of the current directory.

Comment: I first thought it was a path traversal thing - but the file isn't located in the parent of the current directory.  How does it go from machine name, skip the current directory "home", and land in the sub directory called "target"?